# How To Transfer Token From MultiSigWallet To Another Account

Tags: wallet-transfer

How To Transfer Token From MultiSigWallet To Another Account

I have token for multisigwallet in another contract like common token contract.So,How Can I transfer those token to another address or account.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is solved by calling function on behalf of multisigwallet

Comment: If you add more details, it will be much more helpful to others who have the same question that you had.